# Am I missing something about pushing a PS script via domain GPO

Tags: group-policy, powershell, scripting

I've got a script that works.  See [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/256077/programmatically-remove-msft-security-essentials-anti-virus-from-xp-and-win7-mach/256113#256113).

Now my problem is getting it to run via a domain GPO.  On my test clients, I've set the ExecutionPolicy to unrestricted.

I've tried setting it as a startup script. (preferable)

I've tried setting it as a login script.

Nothing is getting executed.  If I run it as an admin user manually, it works.  No dice via GPO.

Edit:  I just tried a test on my XP client that has the Window Management Framework Core (KB 968930) installed.  I associated .ps1 with the powershell program; it was previously associated with Notepad.  I also set a local gpo that pointed to the script.  I rebooted the computer, and it got to the running scripts portion of startup.  It hung there for about 5 minutes before getting to the login screen.  When I logged in, the program was still installed.  No errors in the eventvwr that I can see.

When I was trying to push this out from my domain controller, I went to the Computer Configuration\Window Settings\Scripts and under the Powershell Scripts tab added the file with no parameters.  I have yet to try the domain GPO with the file association added on the client.

What am I missing?

2008r2 and 2003 SP2 DC, Win7 and XP clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a no-go for XP clients.  I managed to get my Win7 clients to work after setting .ps1 to associate with PS instead of Notepad.

Answer (score 2):

Are you setting it to run directly by putting the script path as the "executable"?  Or are you setting the executable to powershell.exe and passing the script path with the -File argument (and potentially other arguments like -NonInteractive)?

I haven't actually tested this myself, but I'm pretty sure you should be doing the latter rather than the former.

Comment: I'm actually just going into the Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Startup section on my domain controller.  There's a tab for powershell scripts and I just load it up there with no arguments.

Comment: I'll edit my question.  I just performed another test as well.

Comment: Hah, I didn't even know that tab existed.  You've taught me something new today and I thank you.  It appears it was added with Win7/2008R2.

Comment: In any case, you might try testing the old-style Scripts tab just to see if it works.  Set the Script Name to the path to powershell.exe.  Then set the Script Parameters to "-File <path to script>".

Comment: You're welcome.  And I think (read: Hope) we may be on to something here.  Will update shortly.

Comment: Crap.  No dice.  Going the old script route didn't work on either client.  Good news is though that I got Win7 to work after setting the file association. I'm thinking it'll be a no go for PS on XP.  Might have to do that one manually.

Comment: I was looking around and thinking about it, and it's probably possible to create a .bat that calls powershell and passes the -File argument.  Haven't tried this as we got around our initial issue, but something to think about.